# Who invented the $1^n$ notation?

Tags: protocol-design

I am  always wondering about the seemingly odd syntax $1^n$ which designates the security strength of a cryptographic algorithm.

Who invented this (odd) syntax and what was the reason for inventing it?

Comment: It definitely comes from theory, and specifically formal language theory, which means it really comes from mathematical logic. If I had to guess, I'd say S.C. Kleene or Church are likely culprits.

Comment: It's not odd at all, it's the string '1' concatenated with itself n times.

Comment: @fkraiem That's odd by definition, isn't it?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Well that depends on your encoding. Usually it's a unary representation of the security parameter, so it's odd if and only if $n$ is odd.